# Isomorphism of sheaves iff injective and surjective

Tags: sheaf-theory

I am wondering if the following proof to show that a morphism $\phi:F\rightarrow G$ of sheaves is isomorphic iff it is injective and surjective is correct:

Suppose it's injective, then $F$ can be identified with a subsheaf of $G$ and from surjectivity this subsheaf must be the whole $G$, so that $\phi$ is an isomorphism of sections, thus sheaves.

Conversely, an isomorphism must be isomorphism on sections, so in particular injective, and then the image of $F$ as subsheaf of $G$ is just $G$ itself, so surjective.

Comment: Be careful: A "surjective" morphism of sheaves need not have surjective components as a natural transformation.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by that. My definition of a surjective morphism of sheaves is just one where the sheaf associated to the image presheaf is precisely the codomain. But if it's already injective, we have already identified the image presheaf with the sheaf $F$.